# Localization alternatives in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization

I'm working on a large GWT project (SmartGWT actually) where the compile time and localization constants management issues are beginning to cause a lot of pain. We compile for 7 languages at this point and the GWT compiles are taking about 60 minutes (across 3 processors on our build machine). If we go to 23 languages in the future this would really kill us.

We've explored the possibility of managing the translations ourselves in a server side database and that would be fine. Unfortunately, the built-in strings that are part of GWT still would require us to build for X languages.

We're also not fond of the whole model in GWT from a translator's workflow perspective. Something like Web4J is really a better model when dealing with thousands of strings but I don't see how this could be integrated to GWT.

To be specific, I'm looking for a way for avoid the high compilation cost when building for multiple languages in GWT. Also, I'd like to move towards a more maintainable and workflow friendly paradigm like Web4J. If anyone knows how to integrate Web4J into GWT and what to do about the native strings of GWT, that would be helpful.

Comment: What is your question precisely ? Do you want a list of alternatives, know how to speed up compilation time, or do you want opinions about GWT integration with Web4J ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to do this is using a [Dictionary](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/Dictionary.html). See the [GWT-I18](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n.html#DevGuideDynamicStringInternationalization) guide to take a look this alternative.

Basically, you have to detect the language used by the user in server side, then the server renders the `index.html` of your application including a javascript object with all the internationalized strings of your application.

[EDITED]

If you want to compile only once, you can [collapse](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/SoftPermutations) properties in your module file:

```
  <collapse-property name="locale" values="*" />
```

Comment: But you still have to compile for all languages because of the embedded GWT string resources, don't you?

Comment: For example, the DatePicker control has localized strings for month names, days of the week, etc.

Comment: Dictionary are thought for implementing your own constants, for Dates and Number gwt uses i18n. The way to change it is using deferred binding and replacing `DateTimeFormatInfoImpl` bu your own implemtation using your Dictionary.

Comment: I forgot to say that if you replace the way GWT internationalizes Dates using your own `DateTimeFormatInfoImpl` based in a `Dictionary`, you WONT have to compile for all languages.

Comment: another way to avoid compiling all languages is merging locale permutations. Updated my comment